# How to catch users with no username?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I'm migrating quite a large community to symfony2. The current user table contains a lot of users with non-alphanumeric chars in the username. In the new version I only allow [a-zA-Z0-9-] for benefits like semantic URLs for each user.

Is it possible to catch users who log in with email/pass and have no username set? I would like them to redirect to a page where they will be able to re-pick a username. The tricky part: they should not be able to touch anything on the site unless they have a correct username.

I thought about a event, from the fosuserbundle but I couldn't find a suitable one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use events. See an example here: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html

Of course the action changing the username should be ignored by the event listener. Just like login and other anonymous actions.

You can return any response, including a redirect, by setting response on an event.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea. How about the AOP paradigm (JMSAopBundle)? Define a pointcut for you controllers (except for the login one):

```
class PrivateEntityInformationPointcut implements PointcutInterface
{

    public function matchesClass(\ReflectionClass $class)
    {
        return $class->isSubclassOf('Your\Controller\Superclass')
            && $class->name !== 'Your\Controller\Access';
    }

    public function matchesMethod(\ReflectionMethod $method)
    {
        return true; // Any method
    }

}
```

Then the interceptor should redirect to the page for setting the username:

```
class DenyEntityAccessInterceptor implements MethodInterceptorInterface
{

    private $securityContext;

    private $logger;

    /**
     * @DI\InjectParams({
     *     "securityContext" = @DI\Inject("security.context"),
     *     "logger"          = @DI\Inject("logger"),
     * })
     */
    public function __construct(SecurityContext $securityContext,
        Logger $logger)
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
        $this->logger          = $logger;
    }

    public function intercept(MethodInvocation $invocation)
    {
        // Check username, redirect using the router, log what's happening

        // It's OK
        return $invocation->proceed();
    }

}
```